# Не запускается .run в ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Права на запуск выставлены. Под sudo запускать пробовал. Текущую директорию ./ и абсолютный путь указывал. Другие раны запускал, то же та же. В графике вообще не ругается. В терминале пишет 'not such file or directory', хотя в ls его показывает. На другом компе с той же версией (3.5.0-41) раны запускаются без проблем по двойному клику.

Comment: нашел ответ, но не могу пока на него ответить тут сам (в форме ответа). Оказывается по умолчанию run'ы 32 бита не запускаются под 64-х битной юбунтой. Самое неприятное, что адекватно не ругается при этом (как написал уже, пишет 'not such file or directory'), напишите кто-нибудь им в баг-репорт, чтоб писал "не могу запусть 32 бит" или что-то вроде.

Comment: Это не баг это фича!

Comment: Вот одно из возможных решений: http://pingvinus.ru/note/bit-32-bit-64-linux-ubuntu , а вот и второе (похожее на первое, но более расширено): http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/1641161

Comment: Тут спрашивают не о том как запустить 32 на 64 , а том "че такая информативная ошибка"

Comment: обычно к "no such file or directory" еще что-то написано, судя по ошибке в написании, этот текст не скопирован, а набран, так - что там наверняка что-то ещё есть.

Comment: Пятак, да в чём ошибка - и до меня уже все поняли! Я попытался ответить, как с этим справиться, что, согласись, намного важнее!